# Check if the element exists in the array, and then replace between two arrays Swift

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a class "Players", and a class "Team". I created two array of Strings calling player1.name, player2.name, etc.
one array with main players and the other array with secondary players

Class:

```
class Players {
    let name: String
    let number: int
    var position:PositionPlayer
    var birth: Date
    let nationality: String
    var height: Double 
    var weight: int
    init(name: String, number: Int, position: PositionPlayer, birth: Date, height: Double, weight: Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.number = number
        self.position = position
        self.birth = birth
        self.nationality = nationality
        self.height = height
        self.weight = weight
    }
```

Class Team is empty (just doing the function on it)

Arrays:

```
var mainPlayers: [String] = []
var secondaryPlayers: [String] = []
```

add elements in arrays:

```
mainPlayers.append("\(player1.name)")
```

How do I make a function in class "Team" that checks the elements of the arrays and does the substitution between the 2 arrays?

e.g. I have 3 main players and 3 secondary players, and I want to put player 4 (secondary player) in place of player 1.

Comment: @Flavio I think you should be using a set instead of an array

Comment: Show your classes.

Comment: SO you want to switch players from the two collections

Comment: @Leo yes, I want to switch them...

Comment: @matt I need to confirm that the player exists within the array to make the switch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the order of the collection doesnt matter you should use a set to make sure there is no duplicated players in your collection:

```
var mainPlayers: Set = ["player1", "player2", "player3"]
var secondaryPlayers: Set = ["player4", "player5", "player6"]

let oldPlayer = "player1"
let newPlayer = "player4"
if mainPlayers.contains(oldPlayer),
    secondaryPlayers.contains(newPlayer),
    let oldMember = mainPlayers.remove(oldPlayer),
    let newMember = secondaryPlayers.remove(newPlayer),
    mainPlayers.insert(newMember).inserted,
    secondaryPlayers.insert(oldMember).inserted {
    print("oldMember", oldMember)   // player1
    print("newMember", newMember)   // player4
    print(mainPlayers)       // ["player3", "player4", "player2"]
    print(secondaryPlayers)  // ["player1", "player5", "player6"]
}
```

If the order of the collection matters the array approach should look like this:

```
var mainPlayers = ["player1", "player2", "player3"]
var secondaryPlayers = ["player4", "player5", "player6"]

if let oldMemberIndex = mainPlayers.firstIndex(of: "player1"),
    let newMemberIndex = secondaryPlayers.firstIndex(of: "player4"),
    case let oldMember = mainPlayers.remove(at: oldMemberIndex),
    case let newMember = secondaryPlayers.remove(at: newMemberIndex) {
    mainPlayers.insert(newMember, at: oldMemberIndex)
    secondaryPlayers.insert(oldMember, at: newMemberIndex)
    print("oldMember", oldMember)   // player1
    print("newMember", newMember)   // player4
    print(mainPlayers)       // ["player4", "player2", "player3"]
    print(secondaryPlayers)  // ["player1", "player5", "player6"]
}
```

Comment: I will post the array approach as well if you need to keep the collection order

Comment: @FlavioGrandini Btw string interpolation is not needed `mainPlayers.append(player1.name)`

Comment: tem como usar esse oldMemberIndex = mainPlayers.firstIndex(of: "player1") sem definir o player 1, deixando vazio pra definir quem vai trocar depois? eu queria usar ele como função dentro da minha classe, mas da erro
Referencing instance method 'firstIndex(of:)' on 'Collection' requires that 'Players' conform to 'Equatable'

Comment: Dificil entender a sua pergunta sem o contexto. Abre outro post e mostra em detalhes o seu problema. Na minha opinião voce deveria conform o seu Player com hashable e trabalhar direto com os objetos (set de players). Quando for implementar a sua função pra substituir um player voce verifica antes se os mainPlayers contem o player que voce quer substituir, se não tiver o player apresenta o erro e retorna.

Comment: Se o usuário que ta fazendo a substituição o ideal é voce apresentar uma lista pra ele selecionar o player, ai não tem como não existir o elemento..

Comment: É exatamente isso que preciso fazer, agora como faz eu nao faço ideia hahahah Parece que quanto mais pesquiso como faz as coisas com swift mais perdido eu fico

Comment: É facil. Aos poucos você vai se familiarizando. E em vez de `class` use `struct`

Comment: No seu caso eu acho que [`UIPickerView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipickerview) como uma [`inputView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfield/1619620-inputview) de um `UITextField`
 é a melhor opção.